# How would I determine where my program is pegging the processor on the server?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, processing-efficiency

Quick background, I've written a service that pulls email from an Exchange server using IMAP and processes it.

The problem (well, one of them) is that the server admin has noticed the program is pegging the processor intermittently.

Now, the problem here is... nothing should be making that happen.  Nothing is particularly intensive, there are no nested loops, and honestly testing is stalled so the process has very little to do!

No, the service runs every 30 seconds... but the processor thing is happening only about three times per hour.  It's relatively regular too according to the graph I was sent.

I have a suspicion that there's something going on when connect to the mail server, but I would need to show that that's when the processor is being pegged.

Only problem is I have no idea how to show that it's happening when I hit a specific bit of code...

Comment: Forgive a dumb question, but are you processing it on the local machine, or is it doing the processing on the Server?

Comment: I'm just pulling the email down from the Exchange server, then doing the processing locally.

Comment: If you stop your program do the spikes still happen on the server?  Are you pulling the emails 1 at a time or all at once?

Comment: This is what benchmarking is for.

Comment: @David: Haven't tried stopping the program, but have seen the process using 99% CPU in task manager.  Pulling up to 15 at a time, but I know there are only 10 waiting on the server.

Comment: @Ramhound Care to elaborate?  :)

Comment: @Telos - Visual Studio has basic benchmarking tools.  There are more elaborate tools that exist also.  Allows you to get a complete picture of the system state during a specific section of code.